# Как сделать ожидание нажатия кнопки от пользователя в телеграмме, при этом сохранять текст который он вводит

Tags: python, telebot

Ситуация следующая, есть бот который отправляет сообщение "Опишите проблему", вместе с этим сообщением у пользователя появляется кнопка на клавиатуре "Создать заявку".
Нужно чтобы после того как появилось сообщение и кнопка пользователь вводит тест проблемы несколькими сообщениями(то есть не одна отправка сообщения, а несколько, так сказать, дать выгориться пользователю), после он нажимает кнопку "Создать заявку" и происходит передача того что он написал на сайт (с передачей проблем нет). Проблема как сохранить, то что вводит пользователь в переменную и завершить запись того что он вводит ТОЛЬКО после того как он нажал кнопку?